# Outlook Web addin throwing error on specific Outlook client but works with OWA

Tags: outlook, outlook-web-addins, crm-outlook-client

We have outlook web addin hosted on Apache server Lets say apache Apache1 Server with proper ssl certificates.

Addin works with no issues in OWA.
But it doesnot work on Outlook client from Apache1 Server.

So in order verify that addin has the issue I have installed one more Apache server Lets say it Apache2 server and installed it on the same account but here I see that it works on Client as well as OWA with no problems.

Now in order to get rid of this I have first repaired the Outlook client but it didnt helped the situation is same. Then I have reinstalled the Outlook Client also no luck here.

Only on Apache1 server the addins is not working on outlook client.

Other senerio I have installed this addin on other machine Outlook client and it works. Only on specific outlook client machine it dont works.

I have fetched the error message from outlook event manager the error is "http_status_not_found".

I understand this is not the addin issue but want to know what the are the other things which effects the outlook client.

[image]

Translation is english : **There was a problem trying to access add-in**

Outlook and the Apache with the addin both run on this machine. A few days ago everything was fine and running. Error message in Outlook: Outlook error when trying to call the addin

Messages in eventlog when trying to call the addin:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft Office 16 Alerts"/> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="0">300</EventID> 
  <Level>4</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-01-24T07:26:27.782113000Z"/> 
  <EventRecordID>422</EventRecordID> 
  <Channel>OAlerts</Channel> 
  <Computer>TS1.boo.de</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-21-343818398-789336058-1708537768-1112"/> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>Activated App</Data> 
  <Data>Id=a327da14-7896-43d0-a049-7d9e34d9ac3b, DisplayName=Mail Analyzer, Provider=[Provider name], StoreType=Exchange, StoreId=A121827C964AC142AB26CDEC5BDEBA08</Data> 
  <Data>Apps for Office</Data> 
  <Data>16.0.11929.20536</Data> 
  <Data/> 
  <Data/> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

20 seconds later two error events:

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft Office 16 Alerts" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="0">300</EventID> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-01-24T07:26:56.438956000Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>423</EventRecordID> 
  <Channel>OAlerts</Channel> 
  <Computer>TS1.boo.de</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-21-343818398-789336058-1708537768-1112" /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>App navigation error</Data> 
  <Data>The Error code is HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND (404)</Data> 
  <Data>Apps for Office</Data> 
  <Data>16.0.11929.20536</Data> 
  <Data>0x194</Data> 
  <Data /> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>

- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft Office 16 Alerts" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="0">300</EventID> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-01-24T07:26:56.439955500Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>424</EventRecordID> 
  <Channel>OAlerts</Channel> 
  <Computer>TS1.boo.de</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-21-343818398-789336058-1708537768-1112" /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>Add-In-Fehler</Data> 
  <Data>Bei dem Versuch, dieses Add-In zu erreichen, ist ein Problem aufgetreten.</Data> 
  <Data>Apps for Office</Data> 
  <Data>16.0.11929.20536</Data> 
  <Data>0x194</Data> 
  <Data /> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Comment: What error do you see when launching the add-in? Could you add a screenshot?

Comment: I have updated the question with screen shot and error translation

Comment: Depending on the version of Office and Windows, Outlook will use either IE or Edge WebView to load the add-in. If you like to try loading the add-in in OWA (or loading the add-in's URL directly) in IE and Edge on the same machine, it may help to reproduce the issue in a web browser. In either case, the log indicates that the add-in's URL is returning a 404, so you may have to check the logs on the web server to determine why the server is returning a 404 for that URL. You also could take a Fiddler/network trace on the client machine to verify the request is reaching the server you expect.

Comment: On OWA everything works good on the same machine and same addin with same addin server , But when it comes to check the same on Outlook client it returns 404. Again the same addin is tested from other machine it works both on the Outlook client as well as OWA.

Comment: What is your build of Outlook and Office? You can also try comparing the IE settings between your machines. One possible issue could be that protected mode is not enabled for the Restricted Sites zone in Internet Explorer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/error-messages/apps-for-office-not-start

Comment: In IE the same Addin Works perfectly fine.

Comment: Are the IE settings on both of your machines the same (ex: is protected mode enabled for both machines?). Certain IE settings have caused issues with loading add-ins in the desktop client. Also, which build of Office and Outlook are you using?

Comment: You can also check if the add-ins load successfully on Word or Excel for the machines by installing them from Office App Store. https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps?product=office